# The Diffrent Gap from top when use Zii cgridview and Tbgridview yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i have trouble in use the zii cgridview and tbgridview bootstrap, when i put table grid use tbgridview bootstap the breadcrum go down to the bottom so far from the top, but if i use the cgridview zii the breadcrum  gap from top it will be normal.

Comment: Use your web inspector (Google Chrome) to find out what the rendered css style is

Comment: just see if there are common classes being used and resolve the css conflicts